# Cannot add SQLBASEUTIL.dll (Gupta) as reference to C# - VStudio 2012

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2012, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase

I am doing a C# project in Visual Studio 2012 (x86). I was able to add `Gupta.SqlBase.Data` to the project but when I run the project if gives me an error related to `SqlBaseUtil.dll`.

> Unable to load SQLBASEUTIL.dll driver library.
>
> Please check your CLIENTRUNTIMEDIR entry inside INI file or check your environment variable path or system path.

Therefore, I tried to add as reference to the project the `SqlBaseUtil.dll`. I could not manage to add this dll. This dll is also added to GAC.
Please help.

Comment: Just some guesswork: I think the assembly that contains the Gupta.SqlBase.Data-Namespace needs to load some files to actually work at runtime. It cannot find the needed files in the search paths, hence the error.
You should check where the SqlBaseUtil.dll resides on your computer and add this path to your global search path.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the mentioned **ini** file exists. If it does, the language files associated with the `SqlBaseUtil.dll` are missing and cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and even after finding the dll and putting it in the same folder as the exe I was trying to run, it still gave the same error.

The problem wasn't that it couldn't find the dll, but rather that it couldn't load it, because it was missing vcredist2005_x86.exe (Microsoft.VC80.MFC).

If anyone else has the same problem, try checking the Event Viewer for more info (Windows Logs > Application).